# local cohomology mayer-vietoris sequence

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, local-cohomology

(*I originally asked this question on Math.SE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/716247/13487). As suggested on meta.MathOverflow ([posting an unanswered Math.SE question on MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1569/36720)), I've waited about a week before reposting it here. Note that although the original question has an answer posted, it didn't actually answer my question.*)

As an assignment in my commutative algebra class, I need to prove the Mayer-Vietoris Sequence for local cohomology:

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $I,J$ $R$-ideals, and $M$ an $R$-module. Show that there is a long exact sequence 
>   $$ \cdots \rightarrow H^i_{I+J}(M)\rightarrow H^i_I(M)\oplus H^i_J(M) \rightarrow H^i_{I\cap J}(M) \rightarrow H^{i+1}_{I+J}(M)\rightarrow\cdots. $$

I've reduced this to proving the following:

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $I,J$ $R$-ideals, and $M$ an $R$-module such that $\Gamma_{I\cap J}(M)=M$. Then $M=\Gamma_I(M)+\Gamma_J(M)$.

However, in trying to prove this, I ended up "proving" that $M/(\Gamma_I(M)+\Gamma_J(M))\cong (\Gamma_I(M)+\Gamma_J(M))/\Gamma_I(M)$, which is certainly false in general---if it were true, then (assuming we've shown $M=\Gamma_I(M)+\Gamma_J(M)$) setting $J=0$, we'd get $\Gamma_I(M)=M$ for every ideal $I$ and every $R$-module $M$, which is clearly false.

**Question: Where did I go wrong?**

Here's my "proof" of the incorrect "fact":

Consider the short exact sequence 
$$ 0 \to \frac{\Gamma_I(M)}{\Gamma_I(M)\cap \Gamma_J(M)} \to \frac{M}{\Gamma_J(M)}\to \frac{M}{\Gamma_I(M)+\Gamma_J(M)}\to 0.\tag{1}$$
Notice that if $x\in M$, so that $(I\cap J)^n x=0$ for some $x\geq 0$, then $I^n(J^n x)\subseteq (IJ)^nx\subseteq (I\cap J)^n x=0$; hence, $J^nx \subseteq \Gamma_I(M)\subseteq \Gamma_I(M)+\Gamma_J(M)$. Thus, 
$$ \Gamma_J\left(\frac{M}{\Gamma_I(M)+\Gamma_J(M)}\right) = \frac{M}{\Gamma_I(M)+\Gamma_J(M)} \tag{2},$$
and so (by a previous homework set)
$$ H^i_J\left(\frac{M}{\Gamma_I(M)+\Gamma_J(M)}\right) = 0 \quad \text{for all}\quad i>0 \tag{3}.$$
Also by a previous homework set, 
$$ \Gamma_J\left(\frac{M}{\Gamma_J(M)}\right)=0. \tag{4}$$
Hence, applying the long exact sequence of $H_J$ to (1), and using (2), (3), and (4), we get an exact sequence
$$0\to \frac{M}{\Gamma_I(M)+\Gamma_J(M)} \to H^1_J\left(\frac{\Gamma_I(M)}{\Gamma_I(M)\cap \Gamma_J(M)}\right) \to H^1_J\left(\frac{M}{\Gamma_J(M)}\right)\to 0. $$
Hence,
$$ \frac{M}{\Gamma_I(M)+\Gamma_J(M)} \cong \ker \left[H^1_J\left(\frac{\Gamma_I(M)}{\Gamma_I(M)\cap \Gamma_J(M)}\right) \to H^1_J\left(\frac{M}{\Gamma_J(M)}\right)\right].\tag{5}$$

Now, since $\Gamma_I(M)\cap \Gamma_J(M)=\Gamma_J(\Gamma_I(M))$, we get
$$ \frac{\Gamma_I(M)}{\Gamma_I(M)\cap \Gamma_J(M)} = \frac{\Gamma_I(M)}{\Gamma_J(\Gamma_I(M))}.$$
From a previous homework assignment, if $N$ is any $R$-module, $R$ is Noetherian, and $J$ is an $R$-ideal, then for $i>0$, the map $H^i(N)\to H^i(N/\Gamma_I(N))$ induced by the projection $N\to N/\Gamma_I(N)$ is an isomorphism. Therefore, (5) becomes 
$$ \frac{M}{\Gamma_I(M)+\Gamma_J(M)} \cong \ker \left[H^1_J(\Gamma_I(M)) \to H^1_J(M)\right],$$
where $H^1_J(\Gamma_I(M)) \to H^1_J(M)$ is the natural map. But by the long exact sequence of $H_J$,
$$ \ker \left[H^1_J(\Gamma_I(M)) \to H^1_J(M)\right] \cong \frac{\Gamma_J(M)}{\Gamma_J(\Gamma_I(M))} \cong \frac{\Gamma_I(M)+\Gamma_J(M)}{\Gamma_I(M)}.$$
Thus,
$$ \frac{M}{\Gamma_I(M)+\Gamma_J(M)} \cong \frac{\Gamma_I(M)+\Gamma_J(M)}{\Gamma_I(M)}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*This is an elaboration on Vinteuil's answer. I did not accept Vinteuil's answer due to the lack of detail.*)

So, it seems that I made a very foolish error: Consider the long exact sequence of $H_J$ that I refer to in the 4th-to-last line of my original post. Written out, it is
$$\Gamma_J(M)\to \Gamma_J(M/\Gamma_I(M))\to H^1_J(\Gamma_I(M))\to H^1_J(M).$$
The *correct* thing to get from this is that the kernel of the last map is the image of the second, i.e.
$$\ker\left[H^1_J(\Gamma_I(M))\to H^1_J(M)\right]=\operatorname{im}\left[\Gamma_J(M/\Gamma_I(M))\to H^1_J(\Gamma_I(M))\right].$$
However, what *I* did was set the kernel of the last map equal to the image of the *first*.

Answer (score 1):

In line -3, first isomorphism.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm not sure what you mean by line -3.

Comment: $ \ker \left[H^1_J(\Gamma_I(M)) \to H^1_J(M)\right] \cong \frac{\Gamma_J(M)}{\Gamma_J(\Gamma_I(M))}$

Comment: Why is that incorrect? The long exact sequence $$\Gamma_J(M)\to \Gamma_J(M/\Gamma_I(M))\to H^1_J(\Gamma_I(M))\to H^1_J(M)$$ implies that $$\ker \left[H^1_J(\Gamma_I(M)) \to H^1_J(M)\right] \cong \frac{\Gamma_J(M)}{\Gamma_J(M)\cap \Gamma_I(M)}$$. But $\Gamma_J(M)\cap \Gamma_I(M)=\Gamma_J(\Gamma_I(M))$.

Comment: Take for instance examples with $\Gamma_I(M)=0 \neq \Gamma_J(M)$.

Comment: Also, could you put your above comments into the actual answer?

Comment: I see what I did wrong. In reference to the long exact sequence in my above comment, I foolishly set the kernel of the third map as isomorphic to the image of the first instead of the image of the second.